# Реклама AdMod вместе с Appodeal?

Tags: android, реклама

Есть ли здесь люди, которые подключали одновременно рекламу AdMod и Appodeal, и сколько вообще можно рекламных баннеров весить в свое приложение?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ответы надо искать на AbMob в консоли разработчика.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja изменил вопрос.

Comment: Так вроде appodeal работает с admob, ты отдельно хочешь подключать их?

Comment: нет одновременно, в этом и вопрос , не будет ли банить аккаунт AdMod и Appodeal, если есть стороние рекламы не от их компании .

Comment: Блин, а вот это хз. Я бы спросил у них на сайте, там 24/7 саппорт работает, если мне память не изменяет

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не советовала вам делать такую интеграцию, это нарушит работу медиации. Стоит учитывать, что Appodeal - это медиатор, а Admob - сеть. Принцип работы Appodeal заключается в том, чтобы сталкивать сети между собой, заставлять конурировать, при интеграции, которую вы описываете, получится, что Appodeal (содержащий в себе более 60 источников деманда, в том числе, Admob) конкурирует с 1 сетью за показ. Медиация в таком случае не будет работать так, как запланировано. Кроме того, Appodeal обеспечивает максимальный филл рейт, поэтому добавлять другие сети не требуется.

Comment: А если автор хочет больше денег и поставить 5 баннеров в ряд?